# Does ora2pg support the SDO_GEOMETRY spatial type?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, oracle-spatial, migration

I've been searching the net up and down for days now and can't find a definite answer to this question, neither on google nor on the official page (http://ora2pg.darold.net/).

Does ora2pg support Oracle's SDO_GEOMETRY spatial type?

If I run ora2pg on an Oracle test table I get an output like

```
CREATE TABLE platzerl2 (
        objectid bigint NOT NULL,
        name varchar(40),
        class varchar(25),
        st varchar(2),
        stfips varchar(2),
        placefip varchar(5),
        houseunits bigint,
        pop2000 bigint,
        pop_class integer,
        arealand double precision,
        areawater double precision,
        shape SDO_GEOMETRY,
        se_anno_cad_data bytea
);
```

Clearly SDO_GEOMETRY should read something like GEOMETRY, Postgres/PostGIS's spatial type.

So, is SDO_GEOMETRY unsupported or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `SDO_GEOMETRY` doesn't appear in the source code (https://github.com/darold/ora2pg) so I'd say you'll need to add support for it yourself.

Comment: could you please post this as answer so that i can mark it as solved question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SDO_GEOMETRY` doesn't appear in the source code (github.com/darold/ora2pg) so I'd say you'll need to add support for it yourself, or manually fix up the `SDO_GEOMETRY` columns using a second pass over your code with `awk` / `sed` / whatever.

ora2pg is written in Perl and looks fairly sane, so I suggest adding `SDO_GEOMETRY` support and sending a pull request on github; that way others who need it later will have support for it.